# SSL Configuration for Kafka Producer

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-producer-api

I've configured SSL for broker (named kafka1) and producer based on following link: https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/KafkaIntegrationGuide/TLS-SSL/KafkaTLS-SSLExamplePart3ConfigureKafka.htm).

unlike the broker, the producer hasn't been configured successfully in the producer.properties file. Because there is Kerberos authentication service with the following configuration and I can't set `security.protocol = SSL` as mentioned in the above link:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
```

In order to produce data to kafka this command is used:

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka1.sgi.ir:9093 --topic test1kafka1 --producer.config /home/pskafka/kafka_2.12-2.4.0/config/producer.properties
```

Finally, The question that I have is how can set SSL in `producer.properties` configuration file?

An image of `producer.properties` configuration file is as bellow:

```
compression.type=none
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
#security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test123
ssl.keystore.location=/var/private/ssl/client1.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test123
ssl.key.password=test123
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
#ssl.client.auth=required
```

Comment: If you want TLS/SSL encryption in flight with kerberos authentication, you need to set security.protocol=SASL_SSL.

Comment: I did security.protocol=SASL_SSL in config file but I confront following error during running data producing.

Comment: [2020-10-28 06:18:14,970] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)